# Target CSS to all but not Firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I know about:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix()
```

But how about the inverse?  Specifically, I'm having an issue with some mobile devices adding a border radius to text input elements which I don't want.  If I set `border-radius: 0` Firefox renders it like this:

[image]

Which just looks terrible.  I'd just like to be able to apply a rule to everything but *not* Firefox since it seems to be very picky about messing with form element styles.

Answer (score -1):

Is this what you're looking for perhaps? I use this reset for webkit browsers that add that border-radius, this does not affect FF:

```
input[type="text"] {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0; }
```

Comment: This doesn't answer my question but it does address the specific concern I've raised above.  Thanks and upvoted for helpfulness.

Comment: I have never tested this myself, but you might be able to "reverse logic" on some @ queries adding a `not`, but I'm not sure if this would work with browser-specific queries.